# Getting Items from Dictionary by key

Tags: c#, dictionary, multi-level

I have this structure:

```
static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> tasks = 
    new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
```

it looks like that

```
[1]([8] => "str1")
[3]([8] => "str2")
[2]([6] => "str3")
[5]([6] => "str4")
```

I want to get from this list all of the `[8]` strings, meaning `str1` + `str2`
The method should look like the following:

```
static List<string> getTasksByNum(int num){

}
```

How do I access it?

Comment: loop all, but it is too heavy

Comment: You should return an IEnumerable rather than a List

Comment: A Dictionary inside a Dictionary?

Comment: Define "heavy?"  Whatever method you use will use a loop...

Comment: @QuangAnh Anh, what is wrong with that? you saw my structure... what other solution do you recommend?

Comment: With a structure like that you'll have to loop through each outer dictionary.

Comment: Since I don't know why do you want to use that structure, I can't give exact suggestions. There is one thing I can say regarding Dictionary: it's performance is not good. Could be because of the .Net implementation.

Comment: @SexyMF You could try using a [`KeyValuePair<int, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) or [`Tuple<int, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) instead of the inner dictionary. Thus your structure would be similar to `Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over all values of the first hierarchy level and use `TryGetValue` on the second level:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach(var inner in tasks.Values)
{
    string tmp;
    if(inner.TryGetValue(yourKey, out tmp)
        result.Add(tmp);
}
```

This solution has a major advantage over all other solutions presented so far:
It actually uses the dictionaries of the second hierarchy level as a dictionary, i.e. the part inside the foreach loop is O(1) instead of O(n) as with all other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

With LINQ, you can do something like:

```
return tasks.Values
            .Where(dict => dict.ContainsKey(8))
            .Select(dict => dict[8])
            .ToList();
```

While this is elegant, the `TryGetValue` pattern is normally preferable to the two lookup operations this uses (first trying `ContainsKey` and then using the indexer to get the value).

If that's an issue for you, you could do something like (with a suitable helper method):

```
return tasks.Values
            .Select(dict => dict.TryGetValueToTuple(8))
            .Where(tuple => tuple.Item1)
            .Select(tuple => tuple.Item2)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this function:

```
   tasks.
      Where(task => task.Value.ContainsKey(8)).
      Select(task => task.Value[8]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's solution is probably best, since it's easier to understand.  But it's possible to use TryGetValue in a linq approach, too:

```
return tasks.Values
    .Select(dictionary => {
        string task;
        var success = dictionary.TryGetValue(yourKey, out task);
        return new { success, task };
    })
    .Where(t => t.success)
    .Select(t => t.task)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you building tasks ?
And if I'm guessing right it's tasks[task_id]([cpu] => "task_name");
I would advice you also build cpu_tasks[cpu]([task_id] => "task_name);

```
static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> cpu_tasks
```

It would require some more maintenance but would give you a faster run on this specific function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> tasks = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();

List<string> strings = new List<string>();
foreach(var dict in tasks.Values)
{
  if(dict.ContainsKey(8))
      strings.Add(dict[8]);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient considering that you can use `GetValue` or `TryGetValue` rather than looping through everything in every dictionary...

Comment: Yes, your edit fixes the problem I raised.  (Editing your answer and then replying as though my comment is wrong is less than endearing, however.)

Comment: Edited 21 hours ago, you replied 21 hours ago, I never saw your comment before I edited. In any case, I noticed myself that I could do it a lot faster yesterday by using a dict[8] so you were right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> tasks = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
var result = string.Empty;

//more human-readable version
var searchValue = 8;
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
     if (task.Value.ContainsKey(searchValue))
         result += task.Value[searchValue];
}

//one-line version
result = tasks.ToList().Aggregate(string.Empty, (a, kvp) => a += kvp.Value.ContainsKey(searchValue) ? kvp.Value[searchValue] : string.Empty);
```